# python multiprocessing.pool but with N cores per process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Python's `multiprocessing.pool` module gives one core per process.  Is there an equivalent that instead gives out **N** cores per process?  i.e. the `multiprocessing.cool_new_pool` defined below?

```
import multiprocessing
def func(x):
    return x**2

TOTAL_CORES = 10 #os.cpu_count() for nonminimal example
N_CORES_PER_PROCESS = 2
#p = multiprocessing.Pool(N_CORES) # multiprocessing with pool
p = multiprocessing.cool_new_pool(TOTAL_CORES , N_CORES_PER_PROCESS) #Desired functionality
results = p.map(func, [i for i in range(10000)])
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()//N)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, resources like cores and memories are just meta-data that guides the work and resource allocation. They are usually not strict boundaries for the tasks (which makes resource sharing more robust).

Which leads to the 1st input argument for Pool being number of processes, not resource-specific requirement like cores. Assuming that your tasks always needs 2 cores, and you want to ensure that the core-to-task ratio never drop below 2.0, you can limit the number of processes directly.

Example, if you have 16 cores, and your tasks needs 2 cores per task, and you might still want 2 cores for your own parent process, you can just set the number of processes to the Pool to be (16 - 2) / 2 = 7. And that should achieve what you want. Hope that helps.